# ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'wide_variable_0'. Problem to plot a stacked bar chart with Plotly

Tags: python-3.x, database, plotly, bar-chart, plotly-python

I have a dataframe as below:

```py
data = {}

data['A'] = [27.011609287429945, 2.502001601281025, 25.05004003202562,
             4.283426741393114, 17.804243394715773, 13.991192954363491,
             6.044835868694956, 2.3618895116092875, 0.9507606084867894]
data['B'] = [48.5282874617737, 11.047400611620795, 1.261467889908257,
             10.11085626911315, 22.13302752293578, 0.11467889908256881,
             3.5359327217125385, 2.675840978593272, 0.5925076452599388]
data['C'] = [21.20794806216801, 3.816643714341924, 32.362777887074564,
             4.131418453669093, 19.47668699586858, 11.036789297658862,
             6.138107416879795, 1.2000786936848318, 0.629549478654338]
data['D'] = [41.784452296819794, 10.048586572438163, 3.0697879858657244,
             8.635159010600708, 19.169611307420496, 8.458480565371024,
             2.9151943462897525, 5.013250883392226, 0.9054770318021201]
data['E'] = [37.79565959522068, 6.31553279687881, 4.998780785174348,
             6.730065837600585, 38.673494269690316, 0.0731528895391368,
             3.340648622287247, 1.6093635698610096, 0.4633016337478664]
data['F'] = [16.438772409601945, 3.2816773017319965, 31.75326648435126,
             2.7651169857186266, 24.39987845639623, 11.090853843816468,
             6.4114250987541785, 2.917046490428441, 0.9419629292008508]
data['G'] = [9.253464461332142, 2.32454179704962, 47.250782297720164,
             3.48681269557443, 12.337952615109522, 18.462226195797943,
             5.274921770227984, 0.6258381761287439, 0.9834599910594547]
data['H'] = [10.129310344827585, 2.9454022988505746, 40.660919540229884,
             20.186781609195403, 15.014367816091953, 5.747126436781609,
             4.166666666666666, 0.646551724137931, 0.5028735632183908]
data['I'] = [11.201962387571546, 2.125919869174162, 58.13573180703189,
             4.6606704824202785, 3.597710547833197, 9.403107113654947,
             8.503679476696648, 0.08176614881439084, 2.2894521668029433]
data['J'] = [29.274004683840747, 1.053864168618267, 48.47775175644028,
             0.0, 5.50351288056206, 9.133489461358314, 4.8009367681498825,
             0.0, 1.756440281030445]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=['apple', 'banana', 'cherry', 'date',
                               'elderberry', 'fig', 'guava', 'honeydrew', 'ichigo'])
```

I try to use `df` to plot a stacked bar plot with the codes below:

```py
fig = px.bar(x=df.columns, 
             y=df.values, 
             color=df.index)

fig.update_layout(xaxis_title='Alphabet', yaxis_title='Percentage (%)')

fig.show()
```

However, I got this error message:

```py
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'wide_variable_0'
```

**How do I fix the problem and plot a stacked bar chart?**

- x-axis: columns `A` to `J`
- y-axis: values (in percentage)
- stacked bar (various colours): index `apple` to `ichigo`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that I could fix the error by using [`DataFrame.transpose()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html).

Here is the solution:

```py
df_t = df.T
df_t
```

```py
    apple       banana      cherry      date        elderberry  fig     guava       honeydew        ichigo
A   27.011609   2.502002    25.050040   4.283427    17.804243   13.991193   6.044836    2.361890    0.950761
B   48.528287   11.047401   1.261468    10.110856   22.133028   0.114679    3.535933    2.675841    0.592508
C   21.207948   3.816644    32.362778   4.131418    19.476687   11.036789   6.138107    1.200079    0.629549
D   41.784452   10.048587   3.069788    8.635159    19.169611   8.458481    2.915194    5.013251    0.905477
E   37.795660   6.315533    4.998781    6.730066    38.673494   0.073153    3.340649    1.609364    0.463302
F   16.438772   3.281677    31.753266   2.765117    24.399878   11.090854   6.411425    2.917046    0.941963
G   9.253464    2.324542    47.250782   3.486813    12.337953   18.462226   5.274922    0.625838    0.983460
H   10.129310   2.945402    40.660920   20.186782   15.014368   5.747126    4.166667    0.646552    0.502874
I   11.201962   2.125920    58.135732   4.660670    3.597711    9.403107    8.503679    0.081766    2.289452
J   29.274005   1.053864    48.477752   0.000000    5.503513    9.133489    4.800937    0.000000    1.756440
```

```py
fig = px.bar(df_t)
fig.update_layout(xaxis_title='Alphabet', yaxis_title='Percentage (%)')
fig.show()
```

[image]